# How to learn advanced C debugger usage?

Tags: debugging, gdb

How to learn advanced debugging techniques?

I am a C/Unix programmer, and as such rely on a good C debugger. I know Sun^WOracle mdb on Solaris, GNU gdb on Linux. I feel comfortable setting breakpoints, examining memory structures and such.

Yet, I know that those tools are way more powerful than that. Macros, custom walkers and I don't know what else. The learning curve on the other hand is very steep, as those tools sometimes seem to be arcane magic.

Any good texts? Practice problems? Other tips?

Answer (score 2):

The [GDB Pocket Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596100272) is worth it's weight in diamonds, rubies, or something way lighter than gold. I use it all the time.

The [online docs](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) are also useful, but I actually like having a book on my desk.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the platform http://advancedwindowsdebugging.com/ is great but I assume from the gdb you aren't on windows